# Ubuntu 15.10 Bluetooth Issues

Tags: unix, ubuntu, bluetooth, sdp

I have trouble with Ubuntu 15.10 Bluetooth.

### 1

oguzhan@oguzhan-SATELLITE-L855:~$ sdptool browse local
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory

### 2

[Bluetooth Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9byzL.png)

### 3

How to fix this problem ?. Please any geek people explain me ?

Answer (score 0):

I know one day someone will come and find it how to solve this issue

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory